# How to distribute internet speed in hotspot?

Tags: download-speed

i use ubuntu 13.04 and use internet from broadband isp.i make my ubuntu pc hotspot and share internet with two of my friends. but the problem is when one of is downloading rest two of us ain't getting any speed.

is there any way to share speed equally?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer, and some research will be necessary.

*I have started down this path, but not yet had the time to fully implement ..*

---

### Start by reading:

Complex Traffic Shaping/Control

http://www.shorewall.net/traffic_shaping.htm

OpenWRT > Linux Packet Scheduling

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/packet.scheduler/packet.scheduler.theory

OpenWRT > Bandwidth Monitoring

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/bwmon

OpenWRT > Network Traffic Control

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/packet.scheduler/packet.scheduler

supermind.org > Thoughts on Lucene, Solr, crawling and vertical search

http://www.supermind.org/blog/series/ubuntu-hotspot

Comment: thanks....... its not a easy process at all. trying

Comment: @ubuntu-freak Have you find any easy way?